# Присоединение таблиц базы данных

Tags: delphi, sql-server, sql

Не получается присоединить таблицы базы данных SQL Server к Delphi7. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Кидаете на форму `TADOConnection`, задаете ему строку подключения. Для MS SQL Server будет что-то вроде:

> Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Data Source=127.0.0.1

Потом кидаете `TADOTable`, указываете в качестве `Connection` ваш `TADOConnection` и настраиваете на использование нужной таблицы.

После этого вытаскиваете на форму `TDataSource`, задаете ему в качестве значения свойства `DataSet` вашу `TADOTable`, и на него уже цепляете компоненты для работы с полями (например с вкладки Data Controls).

Comment: Provider=SQLOLEDB.1
есть построитель строк подключения

Comment: Лучше SQLNCLI - появляется в списке после установки клиентской части MS SQL.